# regex for javascript regular expressions

Tags: c#, javascript, regex

I need to parse some JavaScript code in C# and find the regular expressions in that.

When the regular expressions are created using RegExp, I am able to find. (Since the expression is enclosed in quotes.) When it comes to inline definition, something like:

```
var x = /as\/df/;
```

I am facing difficulty in matching the pattern. I need to start at a `/`, exclude all chars until a `/` is found but should ignore `\/`.

I may not relay on the end of statement (`;`) because of Automatic Semicolon Insertion or  the regex may be part of other statement, something like:

```
foo(/xxx/); //assume function takes regex param
```

If I am right, a line break is not allowed within the inline regex in JavaScript to save my day. However, there the following is allowed:

```
var a=/regex1def/;var b=/regex2def/;
foo(/xxx/,/yyy/)
```

I need regular expression someting like `/.*/` that captures right data.

Comment: you can use http://regexhero.net/tester/ to find regexp for particular text

Comment: You want a regular expression that matches... regular expressions?

Comment: Don't you want to match regex modifiers as well?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Yes I need regex to capture jaavscript regexps.  Tim: I have no issues with modifiers as of now, but it would be an addon

Answer (score 3):

You cannot reliably parse programming languages with regular expressions only. Especially Javascript, because its grammar is quite ambiguous. Consider:

```
a = a /b/ 1
foo = /*bar*/ + 1
a /= 5 //.*/hi
```

This code is valid Javascript, but none of `/.../`'s here are regular expressions.

In case you know what you're doing ;), an expression for matching escaped strings is "delimiter, (something escaped or not delimiter), delimiter":

```
 delim ( \\. | [^delim] ) * delim
```

where `delim` is `/` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"/(?:\\/|[^/])*/");
```

**Explanation:**

```
/       # Match /
(?:     # Non-capturing group:
 \\     # Either match \
 /      # followed by /
|       # or
 [^/]   # match any character except /
)*      # Repeat any number of times
 /      # Match /
```

Comment: When I checked with RegexHero, this expression yields no results

Comment: @Tim you probably meant `\/(?:\\\/|[^\/])*\/` (no delimiters in C#)

Comment: @Jerry: Ah, I read JavaScript and thought he needs a JavaScript regex. In .NET, it's easier :)

Comment: @Tim Oh I forgot to remove the extra backslashes for the escaping x3

Comment: @KrishnaSarma: I misread your question; I thought you needed a JavaScript regex, not a .NET one. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

After several trials with RegexHero, this seems working. `/.*?[^\\]/`. But not sure if I am missing any corner case.

Comment: This definitely fails. Consider `/\\/`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this may help you
var patt=/pattern/modifiers;

•pattern specifies the pattern of an expression
•modifiers specify if a search should be global, case-sensitive, etc.